# less -z4 command's display

Tags: command-line, less

I am trying to use the 
 `less -z4 /var/log/syslog` command to display 4 lines by 4 of the syslog file .However, it displays multiple lines. I am wondering what happens? and if we can use other option or other command to do so

Comment: The option `-z` sets the scroll window size, that is the number of lines scrolled up or down when you press <Space>, <PageUp> or <PageDown>. The default is to scroll one entire screen. I don't understand what you mean by 4 lines by 4.

Comment: 4 is the number of lines I want to be scrolled down. Just at the first instance, les  gives more than for lines when pressing <space>, <PageUp> or <PageDown>. Thanks

Comment: For me it works as advertised. Check whether you have any options set in $LESS, or any environment variables beginning with LESS.

Comment: 'echo $LESS' returns an empty line